# Does spark optimize multiple filter applied to an RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am running a simple Spark application wherein I apply multiple filters over an RDD and ultimately apply an action.

Does Spark go over the RDD multiple times? Or does it optimize and apply multiple filters at the same time (with && operation)?

Answer (score -1):

Every transformation on an RDD creates a new RDD. Let me explain with 2 simple examples:

`RDD -> map -> filter -> print`

This goes over the source RDD, then applies the map function, creating an RDD, then applies the filter, creating another RDD and finally does the `print` action.

`RDD -> map (lets call it RDD-m) -> filter (lets call filter1) -> print`

and

`RDD-m -> filter (lets call filter2) -> print`

Both these are part of the same job.

Here we create a new RDD (called RDD-m) after the first map function. Now we are branching out, applying two filter functions (filter1 and filter2) on the same RDD-m. Then we finally print the 2 resulting RDDs. So here, what might look like is the RDD-m getting reused across the 2 filter functions, but it is not.

Spark starts with the action and creates a DAG tracing back to the source RDD. So it will create 2 DAGs for the 2 different paths and the RDD-m will be evaluated twice.

The way to avoid is to use `persist` method on RDD-m which will avoid duplication.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is going `RDD->filter->filter->filter... ->action` (note the mention of `&&`  so I don't think this answers the question And this "This goes over the source RDD, then applies the map function, creating an RDD," is a bit misleading as it doesn't apply the map function yet, it only does that when an action causes it to "collapse" the DAG and actually evaluate the transforms.

Comment: Thanks  @TheArchetypalPaul for the reply and for clarifying the question.